# Processing large csv file with timestamps

Tags: php, python, mysql, csv

I have a large csv file with

user_id, timestamp, page_id, session_id

I need to figure out how long each user spent on a page. There can be multiple rows for each user and page.

I need to retrieve the largest timestamp for a user and page
I need to get the smallest timestamp for a user and page.

The difference will be the amount of time the user spent on each page.

How do I process a 55MB CSV file and process the data to output the amount of time a user spent on each page?

Can I use PHP? Is that efficient?

Comment: What does this have to do with Python?

Comment: Why is session_id in your csv but not in your algorithm?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can import your data into mysql server and using mysql query to resolve that.

```
SELECT user_id, page_id, session_id, MAX( TIMESTAMP ) - MIN( TIMESTAMP ) AS sec
FROM  csv
GROUP BY user_id, page_id, session_id
```

Comment: the problem is that if the user accesses that page 3 years apart, you would think they love the page

Comment: Lol. That's definitely a flaw in the algorithm. Technically, the times should be sessionized.

Comment: including the session_id should be ok.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done pretty simply in PHP (see http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php).

A rough outline of the solution is as follows:

```
$data = [];

if (($fileHandle = fopen("test.csv", "r")) !== false) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== false) {
        $user_id = (int)$data[0];
        if (!isset($data[$user_id])) {
            $data[$user_id] = new stdClass;
        }

        $record = $data[$user_id];
        $timestamp = (int)$data[1];

        if (!isset($record->min) || $timestamp < $record->min) {
            $record->min = $timestamp;
        }

        if (!isset($record->max) || $timestamp > $record->max) {
            $record->max = $timestamp;
        }

        $data[$user_id] = $record;            
    }

    fclose($fileHandle);
}
```

This sets up a mapping of user ids to min and max times. The calculation should be pretty straightforward once this data is set up.

Comment: problem is (among many) ... you are turning php into a db engine, something it crawls at. Plus last I checked, it is not exactly resilient at multi-user concurrency in the above approach

Comment: I would argue that it depends on how often this data needs to be retrieved. For a one-off, PHP is perfectly efficient. It depends on the use case, which is not entirely clear.

Comment: so you think that data of 100k rows oughta be handled like that. ok. all we need then is apache and file I/O

Comment: a conf file is a good use-case for your approach, not a CSV of data